# Is there a ChromeDriver available for Mac OS X 64 bit?

Tags: webdriver

I using Mac OS X 10.8.5. I was using Firefox driver for testing. I would like to use chrome driver too. I searched and all i got is chromedriver for Mac-32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 64-bit version of Chrome for Mac OS X, thus you also do not need a 64-bit chromedriver. Just use the 32-bit one :) put the executable somewhere in your path.

Question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418223/where-to-download-chrome-driver-for-mac-64-bit

You can monitor this issue for Mac OS X 64-bit chrome support: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18323